# Calculate constant b in primal form SVM using scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

In the case of a binary classification for Support Vector Machines, each new point **x'** is classied by evaluating,

```
y' = sign(w . x' + b)
```

This is the case for the primal problem.

I wanted to find out the classifier equation, for which I need to find the **"w" vector** and the **constant "b"**. I'm implementing it in Python using the scikit-learn package.

In scikit-learn package w vector can be found by the attribute "coef_", but how do I find the value of the constant b?

```
from sklearn import svm
cll = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
cll.fit(X, Y) #X is the instances and Y is the output variable
w = cll.coef_[0]
```

How do I find b?

Note: "intercept_" attribute contains holds the independent term -P from the dual form, and not from the primal form.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: "intercept_" attribute contains holds the independent term -P from the dual form, and not from the primal form.

There is no "independent term" in dual form (dual **optimization** formulation is unbiased). This is the `b` from `y' = sign(w . x' + b)`, which is equivalent to `y' = sign( SUM_i alpha_i K(sv_i, x) + b )`